# Difference between selection sort with array and linked list?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, list, selection-sort

Im wondering what is the logic behind selection sort using array with findmax, and linked list with findmin. Best and worst cases for both?

Comment: Google. It's your friend.

Comment: The developer that uses anything besides `mergesort()` on a linked list gets fired, so he has that to consider on the worst-case side. Beyond that, see the above comment.

Comment: @WhozCraig the developer that uses a linked list gets fired

Comment: @aaronman near-impossible to argue against that, so I won't even bother =P.

Comment: @aaronman okay i'll bite - what do you find so bad about a linked list? Given a situation where insert order matters, will be of unknown size, should take up the minimal space in memory, and should have consistent insertion speed, what would you recommend instead?

Comment: @Rollie cache misses because of indirection would be the only not blatantly obvious one, linked lists are not contiguous in memory and that is a recipe for disaster

Comment: @Rollie I think some of the reason they stick around is for teaching concepts and getting beginners used to useful linked structures like BST's

Comment: @aaronman: Plenty of languages get by with *nothing* being contiguous in memory; for example, although the elements of an array or array-backed list will be contiguous, those elements will be nothing but pointers/references to external objects. C++ is one of the few modern languages where that's *not* the case. Would you say that developers using other languages should all be fired?

Comment: @ruakh that's why you don't use those languages when you want your code to run fast

Comment: @aaronman: That's debatable. Even if true -- are you really arguing that developers in all those languages should be fired?

Comment: @ruakh this question is tagged C++, mistakes always stand out more in C++, so C++ developers that use C++ should be fired, or at least scolded :)

Comment: @WhozCraig Anyone not using the member function `sort()` on a linked-list should be fired ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Selection sort is generically bad. Merge sort is generically good, but can be improved by `std::sort` for random access containers and member functions `sort()` for node based containers.

### Selection sort scales quadratically

Consider the following generic version of `selection_sort`

```
template<class ForwardIt, class Compare = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type>>
void selection_sort(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Compare cmp = Compare())
{
        for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
                auto const selection = std::min_element(it, last, cmp);
                std::iter_swap(selection, it);
        }
}
```

On both `std::array` and `std::list` of length `N`, this has `O(N^2)` complexity: the outer loop processes all `N` elements, and the inner call to `std::min_element` is also of linear complexity, which gives overall quadratic scaling.

However, since comparison based sorting can be done as cheaply as `O(N log N)`, this is **typically unacceptable scaling** for large `N`. As mentioned by @EJP , one redeeming feature of selection sort is that although it does `O(N^2)` comparisons, it only does `O(N)` data swaps. However, for very large `N`, this advantage over most `O(N log N)` sorting algorithms, will ultimately be overwhelmed by the `O(N^2)` comparison cost.

### Generic merge sort to the rescue?

Consider the following generic version of `merge_sort`

```
template<class BiDirIt, class Compare = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<BiDirIt>::value_type>>
void merge_sort(BiDirIt first, BiDirIt last, Compare cmp = Compare())
{
        auto const N = std::distance(first, last);
        if (N < 2) return;
        auto middle = first + N / 2;
        merge_sort(first, middle, cmp);
        merge_sort(middle, last, cmp);
        std::inplace_merge(first, middle, last, cmp);
}
```

On both `std::array` and `std::list` of length `N`, this has `O(N log N)` complexity: the recursion depth is `O(log N)` (since the interval is being cut in half each time) and the call to `std::inplace_merge` is of linear complexity, which gives overall `O(N log N)` scaling.

However, pretty much any serious sorting algorithm contender will distinguish itself not significantly with number of comparisons but rather the associated overhead for accessing and placing the data. Such optimizations can only be done with more knowledge than for the generic version.

### Random access containers can benefit from a hybrid algorithm

Containers with random access iterators can be more cheaply sorted using hybrid algorithms. The `std::sort()` and `std::stable_sort` functions from the Standard Library provide such hybrid algorithms of `O(N log N)` worst-case complexity. Typically they are implemented as IntroSort, which mixes the recursive random-pivot quick sort with heap sort and insertion sort, depending on the size of the various recursively sorted sub-ranges.

### Node-based containers can benefit from a member function `sort()`

Comparison based sorting algorithms make heavy use of **copying or swapping the underlying data** pointed to by the iterators. For regular containers, swapping the underlying data is the best you can do. For node-based containers such as `std::list` or `std::forward_list`, you would prefer to `splice`: only rearranging the node pointers and avoid copying potentially large amounts of data. However, this requires knowledge about the connections between iterators.

This is the reason that `std::list` and `std::forward_list` both have a **member function** `sort()`: they have the same `O(N log N)` worst-case complexity, but take advantage of the node-based character of the container.

Comment: Selection sort does *N^2/2* comparisons, but it has the important property that it only does *N* exchanges.